# Compile error in Apache HAWQ. Cannot find the location

Tags: apache, hawq

I am trying to install Apache HAWQ to my node. I referenced Apache HAWQ wiki page (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HAWQ/Build+and+Install) and successfully completed all the required dependent modules including Hadoop, boost, thrift and etc.

And the following step is to install the Apache HAWQ and below are the commands.

```
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-hawq.git

# The code directory is incubator-hawq.
CODE_BASE=`pwd`/incubator-hawq

cd $CODE_BASE

# Run command to generate makefile.
./configure

make -j8

# Install HAWQ
make install
```

However, when I ran `./configure` and I got the error saying that ..

```
.....
checking for snappy-c.h... yes
checking for library containing snappy_max_compressed_length... -lsnappy
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h usability... no
checking thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h presence... no
checking for thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h... no
configure: error: thrift is required
```

Although I installed and compiled thrift using `configure && make && make install`, the shell command cannot find the thrift library.

So I typed the `find \ -name 'TBinaryProtocol.h*'` to find the location where thrift-relevant modules have been installed. And I got the below message.

```
[root@hawq1 incubator-hawq]# find / -name 'TBinaryProtocol.h*'
/usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h
/root/Downloads/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h
/root/Downloads/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cocoa/src/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h
/root/Downloads/hawq/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h
/root/Downloads/hawq/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cocoa/src/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h
```

It means that I have thrift modules and I think that they are properly installed in my directory. And I followed the instruction suggested by the Apache wiki page by typing `ldconfig -p /root/Downloads/hawq/thrift-0.9.1/lib/`.

But I got the same error. And finally I searched the configure.log file and found the below message, indicating it could not find the location of thrift modules.

```
configure:10377: checking thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h usability
configure:10377: g++ -c -g -O2  -D_GNU_SOURCE  conftest.cpp >&5
conftest.cpp:76:45: fatal error: thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h: No such file or directory
 #include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
```

How to solve this issue? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your thrift install path is `/root/Downloads/hawq/thrift-0.9.1/lib/`. 
Could you try `/usr/local/include/thrift` ?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try install thrift using yum.